# How to redirect to another page after firebase login using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am making a web app using firebase. Till now i have been able to create users and enter their details in firebase database. Now, the problem i am facing is, after logging in, i want the user to be redirected to another page, as shown below. I checked for a similar issue here on stackoverflow and tried to implement it but it is not working. How to do it?

Below is the code:

```
   var msgRef = firebase.database().ref().child('messages');

   document.getElementById('contactform').addEventListener('submit', 
   submitLogin);

   firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if (user) {
     window.location = "after-login.html";
   } else {
      document.getElementById("contact").style.display = "block";
   }
  })

  function submitLogin() {
  var userEmail = document.getElementById("email").value;

  var userPass = document.getElementById("password").value;



  firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, 
   userPass).catch(function(error) {
     // Handle Errors here.
     var errorCode = error.code;
     var errorMessage = error.message;
     // ...
   });
  }
```

The stuff i am trying to do is redirect my page after login to "after-login.html". For need of any more references, please do ask.

Comment: What's the problem with your current code? Did you step through the code with a debugger? If you set a breakpoint in `onAuthStateChanged`, does it get hit?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The problem with the current code is it is not being directed to the "after-login.html" page. Rather it is always running the else part.

Comment: That means that there is no user. You realize that you can only *create* a user once? Every subsequent call with the same email will fail.

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting to a page in Javascript can be achieved via

```
window.location.href = yoururl;
```

In your case you have a `catch`, but the catch is that you do not have a `then`, which will be the callback of your promise. So, call a then and implement the redirect you need inside its callback. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises

An example in the source shown above:

```
doSomething().then(function(result) {
  return doSomethingElse(result);
})
.then(function(newResult) {
  return doThirdThing(newResult);
})
.then(function(finalResult) {
  console.log('Got the final result: ' + finalResult);
})
.catch(failureCallback);
```